# Adding XML parsed data to NSMutableArray in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xml-parsing, nsmutablearray

I am parsing XML response and adding it to NSMutableArray.The problem islast value of XML response is not getting added to NSMutableArray..Couldn't get where I am going wrong?
My XML file looks like this:

```
<IDList>
   <Employee>
      <ID>1</ID>
   </Employee
   <Employee>
      <ID>2</ID>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <ID>3</ID>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <ID>4</ID>
   </Employee>
</IDList>
```

And the code Iam writing for parsing is :

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {



 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"IDList"])
 {
 arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 drr1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

 }
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Employee"])
 { 
 drr1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];        
 }
 srr1=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];

 } 


 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


 [srr1 appendString:string];
 }


 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"ID"])
 {

 [drr1 setObject:srr1 forKey:@"ID"];
 [srr1 release],srr1=nil;
 return;
 }  

 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Employee"]) 
 { 
 [arr1 addObject:drr1]; 
 }    


 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"IDList"])
 {

 [drr1 release];

 }

 [srr1 release],srr1=nil;

 }
```

The result I could see in arr1 is:

```
 (
    {
      ID="1",
    }
    {
      ID="2",
    }
    {
      ID="3",
    }
    {
      ID="",
    }
    )
```

I could not see the last value.How can I get all the items ?

Comment: There is no reason to do `drr1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];` when the element is an IDList. You probably want to allocate space for `srr1` only when you see the tag `<ID>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will fixes anything, but this is what I would do:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"IDList"]) {        
         arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Employee"]) { 
        drr1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [arr1 addObject:drr1]; 
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ID"]) {
        srr1=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
 } 

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
     [srr1 appendString:string];
 }

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ID"]) {
        [drr1 setObject:srr1 forKey:@"ID"];
        [srr1 release],srr1=nil;
        return;
    }  
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Employee"]) { 
        [drr1 release];
        drr1 = nil; 
    }
}
```

Comment: But where should I add it to NSMutableArray ?

Comment: I mean finally I haveto add it to NSmutableArray na after collecting the data ..Where should I do it ?

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot @Nathan for ur help.I got it ..I was strucking my head for this for a week ....Thank u .finally got it ...